# Стоит ли использовать Qt C++?

Tags: qt, c++

Всем привет, около месяца пишу на C++ и вот появилась мысль попробовать Qt, тем более он кроссплатформенный

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, стоит хотя бы ознакомиться с этой чудесной библиотекой. А уж использовать ее или нет - можно в каждом проекте решить отдельно, по ситуации. Например, вряд ли оправдано использование Qt в проектах, которые имеют очень жесткие требования по размеру кода - взять всякий middleware.